# Java HashMap size limit? Some keys are disappearing in Bigram Frequency Count

Tags: java

I am writing a simple bigram frequency count algorithm in Java and encountering a problem I don't know how to fix.

My source file is a 9MB .txt file with random words, separated by spaces.

When I run the script limiting the input to the first 100 lines, I get a value of 1 for the frequency of the bigram "hey there".

But when I remove the restriction to only scan the first 100 lines and instead scan the entire file, I get a value of null for the same bigram search. The key/value pair in the HashMap is now null.

I am storing all the bigrams in a HashMap, and using a BufferedReader to read the text file.

What is causing the bigram (key) to be removed from or overwritten in the HashMap? It shouldn't matter if I am reading the entire file or just the first part of it.

```
public class WordCount {

public static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
public static Map<String, Integer> bi_count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        System.out.println("\nProcessing file..."); 

        while (br.readLine() != null) {
    //  for (int i = 0; i < 53; i++ ) {
            sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
            if (sCurrentLine != null) {
                String[] input_words = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
                for (int j = 0; j < input_words.length; j++) {
                    words.add(input_words[j]); 
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
            countWords(); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private static void countWords() {

    for (int k = 0; k < words.size(); k++) {
        String word = words.get(k);
        String next = ""; 
        if (k != words.size() - 1) {
            next = words.get(k+1);
        }

        String two_word = word + " " + next; 

        if (bi_count.containsKey(two_word)) {
            int current_count = bi_count.get(two_word); 
            bi_count.put (two_word, current_count + 1); 
        }
        else {
            bi_count.put( two_word, 1); 
        }

    }

    System.out.println("File processed successfully.\n");
}
```

Comment: arshajii is right. Anyway, I bet for poorly written `equals()/hashCode()`

Comment: Be more specific by providing your code

Comment: Are your keys mutable? If you mutate a key that will cause it to "disappear".

Comment: Added code to the original post

Comment: @billyswifty You call `readLine()` twice in every iteration, skipping every other line.

Comment: Can you provide your .txt file?

Comment: HashMap.size() is limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE or just over 2 billion.  If there is a bug in the 99.9% of the time it will be in your code, not code which has been tested by 10 million developers over 15+ years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not totally confident this is the cause of your problem, bot you are not reading all lines of your input file.

```
while (br.readLine() != null) {
        sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
```

The line read in the if() statement is not being processed at all - you are missing alternate lines.

Instead try this:

```
while ((sCurrentline = nr.readLine()) != null) {
   //now use sCurrentLine...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looked promising but now I am getting an OutOfMemoryError - I don't think it's recognizing the end of input. Any clue why?

Comment: I haven't found any obvious leaks, but in the method countWords() you could remove a word from your ArrayList once you've added it to the bigram Map. Be careful though: the indexes of all remaining words in the list will reduce by one.

Comment: @billyswifty I would have thought an OutOfMemoryError means you were running out of memory. I would check how much heap you are using and how much you have given the process.

Answer (score 1):

This block of code is wrong because readline is called twice:

```
    while (br.readLine() != null) {
//  for (int i = 0; i < 53; i++ ) {
        sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
        if (sCurrentLine != null) {
            String[] input_words = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
            for (int j = 0; j < input_words.length; j++) {
                words.add(input_words[j]); 
            }
        }
    }
```

I would suggest:

```
    while ((sCurrentline = nr.readLine()) != null)  {
        String[] input_words = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
        for (int j = 0; j < input_words.length; j++) {
                words.add(input_words[j]); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not `while(sCurrentLine != null) { String[] input_words.... }` Then you don't need the if block, and gets a nicer while loop instead of a do

Comment: You are absolutely right, my code was really overcomplicated. Updated using the suggestion of NickJ.

Comment: Thanks, that looked promising but now I am getting an OutOfMemoryError - I don't think it's recognizing the end of input. Any clue why?

Comment: ArrayList throws OutOfMemoryError, if you read more elements than an Array can hold.